# Counting the number of values emitted before the Observable completes?

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, rxjs6

Attempting to verify that an observable emits a certain number of events before it completes.  This is pseudo code:

```
o.pipe(count).subscribe(count=>
  expect(count).toEqual(4));
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `count` operator works as follows:

> Counts the number of emissions on the source and emits that number when the source completes ([source](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/count))

So you can use it like so:

```
obs.pipe(count()).subscribe(totalEmissions => expect(totalEmissions).toEqual(4))
```

Note that you can't really measure how many events occured *before* the original observable completed, because if it didn't complete then you didn't finish counting!

You can, however, take note of the "index" of each emission using `tap`:

```js
let count = 0
obs.pipe(tap(() => console.log("emitted! Index: " + count++))).subscribe(obsValue => {/*...*/})
```

I'm not sure which is your use case, but that's how you can do it.